# Partial sum formula for $\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{bx - x^2}$ at specific limit without using digamma function

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers, digamma-function

Given the following sum:

$\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{bx - x^2}$

(b is an integer constant)

It appears to me that partial sum cannot be calculated without using Harmonic numbers, or Digamma function. From wolfram: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(bx-x%5E2),+x%3D1+to+n

$\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{bx - x^2} = \frac{-\psi^{(0)}(-b+n+1)+\psi^{(0)}(1-b)+\psi^{(0)}(n+1)+\gamma}{b} $

Is it possible that for some specific value of n, the partial sum would be calculable with a simpler formula. If not applicable to this sum, is it something that is possible for any other sum ?  In my example, the partial sum i'm looking for is

$\sum_{x=1}^\frac{b}{2} \frac{1}{bx - x^2}$

You can see in the chart that everything is kind of symmetric, witch is why i was under the impression that the sum (orange line) up to x=1, x=b/2 and x=b-1 would be easier to calculate than the other points.  We also know that 
$\sum_{x=1}^\frac{b}{2} \frac{1}{bx - x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{b-1} \frac{1}{bx - x^2}+ \frac{2}{b^2}$

[image]

Comment: If $b\in\Bbb N$, you get division by zero for $n\ge b$.

Comment: "Is it possible that for some specific value of n, the partial sum would be calculable with a simpler formula." No, the original sum you provide is the simplest form IMHO.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, yes, the sum range must not include 0 or b

Comment: @François Huppé Your question resembles this one: "is there a specific value of $n$ for which the partial sum $\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ would be calculable without the use of Harmonic number?". The answer is "no, because this is the definition of the Harmonic number". You cannot even find a value of $n$ for which the partial sum is an integer. This remark can be generalized by expanding your summand into partial fractions.

Comment: @François Huppé You can find a value for $b$ and $n$ for which the partial sum attains a specific value (which would be a "simple formula"). For instance, for $b=\frac{3}{2}$ and $n=2$ the partial sum is 1.